# Update Tab Index after inserting dynamic elements( form table rows )

Tags: jquery, html

I am django template developer. I have a form in a `<table>` containing Html `input` elements.
Sometimes I need to add or delete dynamic rows containing inputs in the form if user want to add or remove related information. In that case, some times User need to add rows or delete those rows. I have already added`tabindex='some_number'`to the HTML template. There are many forms, approx 10-12 forms with this situation.

So,I want to write some common javascript code that can be used to update`tabindex`es of whole form elements each time if any of inputs, textarea or select list has got added dynamically which I can invoke the function after `inserting or deleting`  a table row .

I tried this:,

```
function addDynamicTabIndexes(){    
 $("form").find("input, textarea, select").each(function(){
   var currentTabIndex = parseInt($(this).attr("tabindex"))
   $(this).attr("tabindex", currentTabIndex + 1); 
 });
}

function removeDynamicTabIndexes(){    
 $("form").find("input, textarea, select").each(function(){
   var currentTabIndex = parseInt($(this).attr("tabindex"))
   $(this).attr("tabindex", currentTabIndex - 1); 
 });
}
```

But not sure why its not working properly. Most of the times it goes back to first element.